# Specifying date range params for $http GET request to Parse DB

Tags: angularjs, rest, parse-platform, angularjs-service

The following is a `GET` request I am making to Parse.com's RESTful API. I want to structure the request to only retrieve records that have been received **today**.

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Order",
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        // WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
        createdAt: /* greater than 8am today, less than or equal to current time */
    }
})
```

After reading from the Parse API docs about Query Constraints, I've modified the $http GET. However, it still returns all Orders.

```
var startDate = new Date();
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
startDate.setHours(8);//set time to 8 am.
$http({ method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Order",
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        where: {
            "createdAt": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": currentTime }
        }
    }
})
```

**EDIT 1:** Upon structuring my get request like so: I receive a 400 HTTP error, containing the following:

```
code: 107
error: "invalid date {1.433264918052e+12}"
```

**EDIT 2 (SOLVED):** I've solved the issue. After resolving the structure of the params property, I learned that the Parse API expects an ISO format DateTime. So, my final version looks like this:

```
var startDate = new Date().toISOString();
var currentTime = new Date().getTime().toISOString();
startDate.setHours(8);//set time to 8 am.
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({ method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Order",
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        where: {
            "createdAt": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": currentTime }
        }
    }
})
```

If someone would like to take this opportunity and give a thorough explanation, I would be happy to give them the answer (e.g. what benefit is there for Parse to use ISO over standard Unix epoch time?).

Comment: For those unfamiliar, the documentation for this REST endpoint is here: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries

Comment: @ShotgunNinja So I've added the param using the query constraints. I'll add the params to show what I've done. But it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Realized that I posted the answer in the question a long time ago. Updating this with an official answer for posterity.*

I've solved the issue. After resolving the structure of the params property, I learned that the Parse API expects an ISO format DateTime. So, my final version looks like this:

```
var startDate = new Date().toISOString();
var currentTime = new Date().getTime().toISOString();
startDate.setHours(8);//set time to 8 am.
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({ method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Order",
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        where: {
            "createdAt": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": currentTime }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the from and to dates timestamp to pass a range of date. Try something like this.

```
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setHours(8);//set time to 8 am.

$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Order",
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        createdFrom: startDate.getTime(),
        createdTo: new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

On the server side you can convert the timestamp to date object to pass it to DB stored proc or query.

Comment: This is good advice for invoking a cloud function, but the OP is asking about REST api, which would require that the constraints are specified as described here: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries

Comment: I wasn't aware of this api. Thx for educating me :)